# How to Containerize a Vue.js app?

Tags: node.js, docker, vue.js, vuejs2, dockerfile

I am unable to access the site locally on the http://172.17.0.2:8080/ in Chrome, I get "172.17.0.2 took too long to respond".

I used the inspect command to obtain the IP address of the container.

```
docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}} e83c95d05d63
```

The run command that I used.

```
docker run -it -p 8080:8080 --name portfolio-vue portfolio-vue:v1
```

And my Dockerfile

```
FROM node:7.7-alpine

ADD package.json /tmp/package.json
RUN cd /tmp && npm install

RUN mkdir -p /opt/portfolio-vue && cp -a /tmp/node_modules /opt/portfolio-vue-app

WORKDIR /opt/portfolio-vue
COPY . /opt/portfolio-vue

EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a default vue-cli setup, `npm start` (the command you are using) runs `npm run dev`.

And, again, by default, `npm run dev` binds to localhost only.

Add `--host 0.0.0.0` to your `webpack-dev-server` line in `package.json` so you can access it from **outside** the docker container:

From something like:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js",
```

To something like (`add --host 0.0.0.0`):

```
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js --host 0.0.0.0",
```

**Note:** I'm assuming, because you used `CMD ["npm", "start"]`, you are creating a container for development or debugging purposes. If you are targeting production, you should really consider generating the bundle (`npm run build`) and serving the generated files directly on a HTTP server like nginx (which could be created in a docker as well).

Comment: Notice that this solution doesn't bind to all addresses, only to ipv4 ones, you are basically excluding more than half of the internet

Comment: In newer webpack versions you have `--disable-host-check`, but, in the current vue-cli, `--host 0.0.0.0` is as good as it gets. One may try to replace `0.0.0.0` with the IPv6 equivalent, but I have never done that and can't vouch if works or not.