# Containerizing a Vue application does not display webpage on localhost

Tags: docker, vue.js, docker-compose

I'm trying to containerize my vue application I created using vue-cli. I have a docker-compose.yml file that looks like this:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  npm:
    image: node:current-alpine
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    working_dir: /app
    entrypoint: [ 'npm' ]
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
```

I have in the same directory the docker-compose.yml and the /app where the vue source code is located.

```
/vue-project
    /app (vue code)
    /docker-compose.yml
```

I install my node dependencies:

```
docker-compose run --rm npm install
```

They install correctly in the container as I see the folder appear in my host.

I am running this command to start the server:

```
docker-compose run --rm npm run serve
```

The server starts to run correctly:

```
  App running at:
  - Local:   http://localhost:8080/

  It seems you are running Vue CLI inside a container.
  Access the dev server via http://localhost:<your container's external mapped port>/

  Note that the development build is not optimized.
  To create a production build, run npm run build.
```

But I cannot access it at http://localhost:8080/ from my browser. I've tried different ports, I've also tried to run the command like this:

```
docker-compose run --rm npm run serve --service-ports
```

But none of this works. I've looked at other dockerfiles but they are so different from mine, what exactly am I doing wrong here?

```
docker ps -a
```

is showing these:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                 COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                           PORTS     NAMES
cf0d5bc724b7   node:current-alpine   "npm run serve --ser…"   21 minutes ago      Up 21 minutes                              docker-compose-vue_npm_run_fd94b7dd5be3
ff7ac833536d   node:current-alpine   "npm"                    22 minutes ago      Exited (1) 22 minutes ago                  docker-compose-vue-npm-1
```

Comment: Can you do a `docker ps` and edit your question with the output?

Comment: I have updated the post with the request information.

Comment: What's your final goal with this setup?  It seems like you're trying to use some Node engine to run code that's on your host, without really using any of the Docker image system; would it be easier to install Node on the host as well and directly use `node` and `npm` commands?

Comment: `Running at: http://localhost:8080/` is a warning sign to me; processes inside containers generally need to be listening on the special 0.0.0.0 "everywhere" address or else they won't be reachable from outside the container.  Does [How to Containerize a Vue.js app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49758077/how-to-containerize-a-vue-js-app) describe your situation?

Answer (score 1):

Your compose-file instructs docker to expose the container's port 8080 to the host's port 8080, yet your docker ps output shows the container is not listening.

Is it possible your containerized app is not listening on 8080?